How to replace a specific field inside a JSON string in each row of a csv file in Python with a random value?
I have a CSV file named input.csv with the following columns:



row_num
start_date_time
id
json_message




120
2024-02-02 00:01:00.001+00
1020240202450
{'amount': 10000, 'currency': 'NZD','seqnbr': 161 }


121
2024-02-02 00:02:00.001+00
1020240202451
{'amount': 20000, 'currency': 'AUD','seqnbr': 162 }


122
2024-02-02 00:03:00.001+00
1020240202452
{'amount': 30000, 'currency': 'USD','seqnbr': None }


123
2024-02-02 00:04:00.001+00
1020240202455
{'amount': 40000, 'currency': 'INR','seqnbr': 163 }



I'm using python3 to read this CSV file and I need to replace seqnbr field under json_message column with a random integer digit for each row. If the seqnbr contains None then that row should not be replaced with random seqnbr rather it should be retained as is. The delimiter for my CSV file is the pipe (|) symbol. I'm using the below Python code to replace the file with the random generated integer value but still it doesn't overwrite it and here is my code:
def update_seqnbr(cls):
    filename = 'input.csv'
    seqnbr_pattern = "'seqnbr': ([\s\d]+)"
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        datareader = (csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
        next(datareader, None)  # skip the headers
        for row in datareader:
            json_message = row[3]
            match = re.findall(seqnbr_pattern, json_message)
            if len(match) != 0:
                replaced_json_message = json_message.replace(match[0], str(random.randint(500, 999)))
                row[3] = replaced_json_message
                x = open(filename, "a")
                x.writelines(row)
                x.close()

Below is how my file should look like:



row_num
start_date_time
id
json_message




120
2024-02-02 00:01:00.001+00
1020240202450
{'amount': 10000, 'currency': 'NZD','seqnbr': 555 }


121
2024-02-02 00:02:00.001+00
1020240202451
{'amount': 20000, 'currency': 'AUD','seqnbr': 897 }


122
2024-02-02 00:03:00.001+00
1020240202452
{'amount': 30000, 'currency': 'USD','seqnbr': None }


123
2024-02-02 00:04:00.001+00
1020240202455
{'amount': 40000, 'currency': 'INR','seqnbr': 768 }



Can someone please help me with this?

json_message is not valid JSON in this example though - it is a Python dict "repr". Do you actually have raw json data or not?

@jqurious this is a Python dict repr. To make this as a valid JSON, we then use json_string = (col[3]).replace("'", '"') and we pass Jsonb(eval(json_string)) in our SQL query.

I made a few changes to your code, using csv to write the new csv too, and most importantly unidenting the write part, that was ignoring the None lines:
def update_seqnbr(cls):
    filename = 'input.csv'
    seqnbr_pattern = "'seqnbr': ([\s\d]+)"
    with open(FILENAME, 'a', newline='') as targetfile:
        targetcsv = csv.writer(targetfile, delimiter='|')
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            datareader = (csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
            targetcsv.writerow(next(datareader, None))  # skip the headers
            for row in datareader:
                json_message = row[3]
                match = re.findall(seqnbr_pattern, json_message)
                if len(match) != 0:
                    replaced_json_message = json_message.replace(match[0], str(random.randint(500, 999)))
                    row[3] = replaced_json_message
                targetcsv.writerow(row)

Here's the output:
row_num|start_date_time|id|json_message
120|2024-02-02 00:01:00.001+00|1020240202450|{'amount': 10000, 'currency': 'NZD','seqnbr': 961}
121|2024-02-02 00:02:00.001+00|1020240202450|{'amount': 20000, 'currency': 'NZD','seqnbr': 863}
122|2024-02-02 00:03:00.001+00|1020240202450|{'amount': 30000, 'currency': 'NZD','seqnbr': None }
123|2024-02-02 00:04:00.001+00|1020240202450|{'amount': 40000, 'currency': 'NZD','seqnbr': 666}


i tried this and what's happening is the original file is appended with new rows containing the updated value for seqnbr and it runs in an infinite loop with same set of original records copied over and over again with new values.

It works perfectly if i change the filemode from 'a' to 'r+' for the targetfile. Thanks heaps

Oh sorry, I though filename and FILENAME pointed to 2 different files (input.csv and output.csv for example). Glad you were able to adapt it.


str.json_decode() to convert json to struct.
struct.with_fields() to update seqnbr field.
when/then and is_not_null() to conditionally affect non-null values only.
np.random.randint() or .sample() (thanks for @jqurious to pointing out) to create list of random integers.
struct.json_encode() to convert back to json.

#import numpy as np

df.with_columns(
    pl.col.json_message.str.json_decode()
).with_columns(
    pl.col.json_message.struct.with_fields(
        seqnbr = 
            pl.when(
                pl.field("seqnbr").is_not_null()
            ).then(
                pl.int_range(500, 999).sample(pl.len())
                #np.random.randint(500, 999, len(df))
            )
    ).struct.json_encode()
)

┌─────────┬────────────────────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ row_num ┆ start_date_time            ┆ id            ┆ json_message                                   │
│ ---     ┆ ---                        ┆ ---           ┆ ---                                            │
│ i64     ┆ str                        ┆ i64           ┆ str                                            │
╞═════════╪════════════════════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 120     ┆ 2024-02-02 00:01:00.001+00 ┆ 1020240202450 ┆ {"amount":10000,"currency":"NZD","seqnbr":850} │
│ 121     ┆ 2024-02-02 00:02:00.001+00 ┆ 1020240202451 ┆ {"amount":20000,"currency":"AUD","seqnbr":841} │
│ 122     ┆ 2024-02-02 00:03:00.001+00 ┆ 1020240202452 ┆ {"amount":30000,"currency":"USD","seqnbr":null}│
│ 123     ┆ 2024-02-02 00:04:00.001+00 ┆ 1020240202455 ┆ {"amount":40000,"currency":"INR","seqnbr":937} │
└─────────┴────────────────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


Nice! I think the random number can also be done with an expression: pl.int_range(500, 999).sample(pl.len())

thanks, haven't thought about sample, I'll add it to the answer

In python polars, this can be achieved as follows.

Use pl.Expr.str.json_decode to convert the json_message column to a struct column with one field for each JSON field.
Use a pl.when().then() construct to conditionally replace the "seqnbr" field in the struct column with a random integer.
Use pl.Expr.struct.json_encode to convert the struct column back to a column of JSON strings.

import numpy as np

(
    df
    # convert json_message to struct column
    .with_columns(pl.col("json_message").str.json_decode())
    # conditionally replace seqnbr values
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("json_message").struct.with_fields(
            pl.when(
                pl.field("seqnbr").is_not_null()
            ).then(
                np.random.randint(0, 200, size=df.height)
            ).alias("seqnbr")
        )
    )
    # convert json_message to json string
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("json_message").struct.json_encode()
    )
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ row_num ┆ start_date_time         ┆ id            ┆ json_message                                    │
│ ---     ┆ ---                     ┆ ---           ┆ ---                                             │
│ i64     ┆ datetime[μs]            ┆ str           ┆ str                                             │
╞═════════╪═════════════════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 120     ┆ 2024-02-02 00:01:00.001 ┆ 1020240202450 ┆ {"amount":10000,"currency":"NZD","seqnbr":108}  │
│ 121     ┆ 2024-02-02 00:02:00.001 ┆ 1020240202451 ┆ {"amount":20000,"currency":"AUD","seqnbr":133}  │
│ 122     ┆ 2024-02-02 00:03:00.001 ┆ 1020240202452 ┆ {"amount":30000,"currency":"USD","seqnbr":null} │
│ 123     ┆ 2024-02-02 00:04:00.001 ┆ 1020240202455 ┆ {"amount":40000,"currency":"INR","seqnbr":43}   │
└─────────┴─────────────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

